# Supplying parameters to pregmatch

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following php code from php.net

```
<?php
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

I don't get why they are using '`/php/i`' not('`php`') for matching. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so called ["perl regular expression" syntax](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), which originated in Perl but commonly used in many languages. `/` characters delimit the regular expression, and the last `i` character is an [option](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifying matching behavior - in this case, saying that the match should be case insensitive, i.e. match all strings like "PHP", "php", "PhP", etc.

You can read more on regular expressions in the [PHP manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

If you're asking why they don't use spaces around - that depends on what you want to find. I would recommend using `/\bphp\b/i` for matching whole words. `\b` means "word boundary".

Answer (score 1):

You could write `/ php /i`, but that will indicate you want your "PHP" string surrounded by spaces, which is not a great idea and in fact will fail this test. the `/.../` notation is the way you write perl style regular expression. it's just `/<pattern>/<flags>` that's all

Answer (score 1):

PHP regexes for the `preg_*` functions (PCRE) use delimiters as is described [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Basically, your expression begins and ands with a delimiter, and after the delimiter you could place modifiers. The `i` modifier makes the expression case insensitive. Other modifiers are described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

And if you are looking for a fixed string you should use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead. That is faster.